# Ruby app stop responding after ssh logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, puma

I have Ruby app up and running with a puma server. It runs on a virtual machine.

When I connect to this machine over ssh everything works perfectly. *However*, if `ssh logout` and refresh the page I see a blank page and

*"Request Method:GET;
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error"* in the network console.

If I `ssh login` - it works again.

I tried to start the puma server with:

> puma -d

and

> pumactl start -d

started in screen. But the result is the same.

I don't know Ruby at all, but have to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the puma server with [nohup](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
>
> screen - screen manager with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wrote, that I tried to launch puma in screen. But it didn't help me:(. After I logout from ssh session I get only blank page

Comment: I guess the problem not in puma server, because when I ssh login, there is puma process '(phoenix   7103  0.7  0.8 840164 65736 ?        Sl   14:31   0:03 /home/phoenix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/puma)'  and it starts to display web form correctly.

Comment: @inearth by more details on you error I mean the error in your app log file.